# If I open a document from a USB flash drive but do not save it to the computer, can someone access the file’s contents after I remove the drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, security, privacy

I have a USB flash drive with confidential information on it and I will need to access this information on someone else's computer. The computer runs Windows 7 and has Microsoft Office 2007. If I open the document but do not save it to the computer's hard drive—just scroll through the information—will it be possible for a subsequent user to retrieve the document and open it after I remove the USB drive?

Since it is a public computer, I cannot install any programs that will wipe the hard drive. I don't care if a subsequent user sees that I have used a thumb drive, or that I opened a file. I just don't want anyone to be able to access the information in that file once I remove the thumb drive.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!** If this is a public computer or a machine that you do not control, you have to assume that there are terrible things on it that are out to steal your stuff and ruin your day.

Even if the OS hasn't been tampered with, the page/swap file very well could contain documents in part or in full, especially if the program you used to look at your files wasn't completely exited. Unless you specifically tell it to, Windows doesn't make any efforts to securely remove chunks of memory that are no longer in use from the page file. Further reading: [this Security.SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29350/54376). Basically, somebody could just boot the computer from other media and trawl through `\pagefile.sys`.

There are all kinds of ways for people to spy on you if they have administrative access to the machine. Programs running as admin can debug any user's processes and read/write anywhere in memory. Anything that passes through RAM (i.e. anything you can see), no matter whether it ever goes on disk, could get caught by sophisticated software. If there are rootkits in play, it might not even be possible to see that shady things are running. An simpler approach, however, would just be to copy all files off of every removable device that gets inserted; this could be accomplished with just Task Scheduler and a bit of batch scripting.

**If you can't trust a computer, you shouldn't handle sensitive data on it.**

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, 100% no. If the document can only be read from the USB flash drive then after you disconnect the USB flash drive, the computer cannot have access to the contents of that document. The only content I know for a fact does get cached locally while viewing is web content; so if somehow this document is viewed via a web browser that would be a risk. But is easily solved by clearing the browser cache before you leave the computer.

That said, if the document is being opened in a program that keeps track of recently opened documents the name of the document might show up in an “Open Recent” menu. You say this might not be a big deal, but it depends on what the document is, what you are protecting and what damage might be caused if the name of that document is known.

For example, I take a USB flash drive to a local FedEx/Kinkos (copy shop in the U.S.) and use their computers to view the document. The next person could see that I opened a document named “Giacomo1968’s Bank Account Info” and that potentially opens me up to be targeted by someone who either works at FedEx/Kinkos or maybe even the next person who uses the computer. So your best bet is to title the document something generic and bland that does not tip anyone off to the contents inside.

Even more of an issue if I decide to print the document on a computer/copy-machine at FedEx/Kinkos. Yes, I can print items myself, but you have 100% no clue what happens to the spooled document data after you are done. Lots of corporate security breaches have actually come form copy machine hard drives not being wiped before being tossed to the curb. Someone salvages that hard drive, checks the print spool and there you go… Instant data leakage from a discarded hard drive.

Yes, that is a little bit paranoid the last two items. But the reality is if you are using public computer/copy machine with personal data then that is the risks you need to be aware of.

In your case, just opening the document would not really expose the data contained in that file to anyone else after the drive is removed.

Comment: If it was viewed, might you not have cached contents?  If it was edited, many programs save working drafts even if you don't save the file.  These typically wouldn't be file copies sitting in an obvious place, but couldn't there be at least portions recoverable from the computer?

Comment: wouldn't Word leave auto-saves on the HD? Even if it deleted them at close, an enterprising individual could trawl the drive.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, yes. Not easy, not always possible but still...

There is auto-save feature that keeps a copy at `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\`. It **should** be deleted after you close the file but it works sometimes different that theoretical it supposed to.